# How to use php inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have created a variable `($latlon)` in php via an sql query like so...

```
// ...
if ($result->num_rows >0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["userid"] . latitude: . $row["latitude"] . 
        longitude: . $row["longitude"] ;

         $latlon = $row["latitude"] . "," . $row["longitude"];
```

and now i would like to use either the variable `$latlon` or `$row["latitude"]` & `$row["longitude"]` in some javascript code that displays a map which looks like this. Ideally i would like my php variable to go in here **(51.508742,-0.120850)** because these coords will continually change.

```
<script>
function initialize()
{
    var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng**(51.508742,-0.120850)**,
        zoom:7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}

function loadScript()
{
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/
    js?key=&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
window.onload = loadScript;
</script>
```

any help will be appreciated. thank you

Comment: Provided your page has a php file extension you can use: center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row["latitude"];?>,<?php echo $row["longitude"];?>),

Comment: thx everyone, gonna try all these suggestions back in a mo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should echo the $latlon variable inside php tag. So the line will be as following: `new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latlon;?>)`. I assume you have the correct syntax for the js in the php `$latlon` variable.

Remember, this will only work if it is a php file you are placing the code on.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are rendering the page using html you could could put that variable in a hidden input element and retrieve it from javascript later.

Like this:

```html
<input id="latlon" type="hidden" name="name" "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($latlon); ?>" />
```

Comment: Please edit your answer with more of the text and an example before it gets flagged being _low quality_

Comment: hi toskv, how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="lat" value="<?php echo $lat; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="long" value="<?php echo $long; ?>">
```

And fetch those values using JS selector Like this:

```
var lat=document.getElementById('lat');
var long=document.getElementById('long');
```

Comment: i split my variable in two like this  $lat = $row["latitude"]; & $lon = $row["longitude"];

Comment: then------   <input type="hidden" id="lat" value="<?php echo $lat; ?>">
                 <input type="hidden" id="lon" value="<?php echo $lon; ?>">

Comment: but only the frame of the map is showing, no detail.